# rspec private method test with factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

**cashout.rb**

```
class Cashout < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :partner
private
  def partner_exist?
    if self.partner.nil?
      errors.add(:base, "There is no partner! ")
      return false;
    end
    return true
  end
end
```

**cashout_spec.rb**

```
context 'should check partner existence' do 
    it 'if partner is not nil' do 
      @company = Factory(:company) 
      @partner = Factory(:partner, :company => @company)
      @cashout = Factory.build(:cashout, :partner => @partner)
      @cashout.save
      @cashout.partner_exist?.should eql(true)
    end
end
```

These are my model file and test file.The test results is

```
1) Cashout should check partner existence if partner is nil
     Failure/Error: @cashout3.partner_exist?.should eql(false)
     NoMethodError:
       private method `partner_exist?' called for #<Cashout:0x007f822189dfa0>
     # ./spec/models/cashout_spec.rb:47:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Do you know how can I test private methods ?

Comment: I assume that `partner_exist?` gets invoked either in another method or in a callback, so why don't you just test whether there is a `"There is no partner!"` error in your model once you call `save` for both instances where there is and isn't a `partner`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call private methods via `send`:

```
@cashout3.send(:partner_exist?).should eql(false)
```